# Secure ISO verification?

Tags: iso

How can I securely verify the ISO?

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS from http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/. The download, the MD5/SHA1/SHA256 sums and PGP signatures are given over HTTP (insecure), I could not find the equivalent over HTTPS (secure), and I am not running Ubuntu so I cannot verify the PGP signatures using the internal keys.

Also, the ISO verification should be mentioned in the Download page or in the Installation Guide; it is not. One has to search for it, and the average user will not know they have to do it. It's irresponsible of Canonical to provide a major Linux distribution insecurely by default.

--Thibaud

Comment: "HTTP (insecure)" HTTP might be insecure but that does not make the "sums are provided over HTTP" insecure. Providing it over HTTPS is -less- secure since HTTPS does not add any extra security to the checksums provided.

Comment: To add: "apt-get" also uses HTTP. Is that insecure? No. See https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt

Comment: @Rinzwind,The trust has to start somewhere. With HTTPS, I trust that my browser trusts the Ubuntu certificates (that's my choice to trust or not to trust the browser). Whereas with the Ubuntu Download page over HTTP (insecure), I have no choice of trust, I would have to take a leap of faith that there is no adversary MITM, which I won't. Can you guarantee that the ISO and sums that arrived at my end have not been tampered with? No you can't. Maybe my ISP or my router is compromised. So, how can I securely verify the ISO?

Comment: @Rinzwind, also, with apt-get I can choose which repos to trust or not.

Comment: Also, the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto ask to Obtain the public key from the Ubuntu key server using hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com but HKP uses HTTP on TCP port 11371 which is insecure too (clear text).

Comment: It's the infamous TOFU problem, trust on first use, that plagues TLS, SSH, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use

Comment: I FOUND IT. Use a web client to the secure Ubuntu keyserver (over HTTPS, assuming your web client already trusts the Ubuntu keyserver certificate) and replace the search key in the parameter as needed: https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xFBB75451

Comment: Also, verify with SHA256, not with the weaker MD5 or SHA1.

Comment: I don't understand why the documentation and most everything on ubuntu.com is served over HTTPS (good) whereas the critical part - ISO checksums and signature - are provided over HTTP (insecure) and there is no information about ISO verification on the Download page and Installation Guide. One has to search for the ISO verification page, and know the workaround to verify securely. I'm starting to believe it's a backdoor left on purpose for state agents to tamper when needed.

Comment: So file a bug report  ;-) The answer probably will be: HTTPS does not add extra security when it is about providing a checksum. You are aware of https://www.linuxmint.com/ ? Is that secure? http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2994

Comment: @Rinzwind, as I said, at least HTTPS will shift the trust to the browser. Right now the only option is leap of faith.

Comment: UPDATE: I was incorrect. It does not matter if the ISO, public key, and checksums, are provided insecurely (although it would be preferable for most users), as long as the public key fingerprint is provided securely, which it already is, although it is not very obvious for users not experienced with PGP. So I updated the VerifyIsoHowto to make it more obvious. Remains the Download page and Installation Guide to mention the need to verify the ISO. See more of the discussion at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/1564313